# Pass a view as a parameter to the url filter

Tags: html, django, url

What happens is that I want in my header template that I will embed in my main page to have the links to the other templates and according to what I researched I find that using the url filter and passing it a view should work but in my case it does not work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <li>
              <ul><a href="{% url 'Home'%}">Principal</a></ul>
              <ul><a href="{% url 'Informacion'%}">Informacion</a></ul>
              <ul><a href="{% url 'Imagenes'%}">Imagenes</a></ul>
            </li>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def Home(request):
    return render(request,"principal.html")

def Informacion(request):

    return render(request,"Informacion.html")

def Imagenes(request):
    
    return render(request,"images.html")
```

```
"""
URL configuration for ProyectoGit project.

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Gestiondepedidos.views import Home,Informacion

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Casa/',Home),
    path('Casa/Info',Informacion),
]
```

This produces Reverse for 'Home' not found. 'Home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Share the `urls.py`

Answer (score 2):

The route names are defined in your `urls.py`, your file should look like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import home, informacion, imagenes

urlpatterns = [
   path("/", home, "home"),
   path("/informacion/", informacion, "informacion"),
   path("/imagenes/", imagenes, "imagenes")
]
```

Comment: That's my url.py

Comment: You don't have the last part for your urls, a path is defined like this: 1. path name -> `/casa`, 2. view method -> `home`, 3. url name -> you didn't define this, but this should be `home`